# Is it possible to trigger a method repeatedly even if app is in foreground or background or killed state in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Currently I am using NSTimer to trigger a method based on the interval(eg:Daily, Weekly, Monthly etc). So I need to trigger my method  based on the interval even if app is in background or killed state. How it's possible by using NSTimer or any other way to implement this requirement in iOS.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question and show what you have already tried using a [example]. See also [ask].

Comment: iOS is *not* macOS. More, how would you assume *any* app, even one on a desktop, would trigger anything on an app that is "killed"? You need to code it to (a) check your server when it's (b) either opened from a "killed" state or even (c) move to the foreground.

Comment: Can you add more description of what that method does?

Comment: This requirement is for automatic backup to iCloud functionality. I have a picker with 3 options like Daily, weekly, monthly and when user select 'Daily' as option, need to trigger a method which contains code for taking auto backup to iCloud after 24 hours .This trigger also need to fire every 24 hours if user select 'Daily' as interval. If user select the option as 'Weekly', need to reset the previous request and fire method with new option. I need to fire my method even app is in foreground or background or killed state. Currently I am using NSTimer for this implementation in Objective C.